# Why my GestureDetect not working in my widget tree?

Tags: flutter

I developed very basic Login screen for my project.

But I have some issue about that.

```
   GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("PRESSED");
                },
                child: Text("Register Now",
                    style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT),
              ),
```

Im trying to use basic GestureDetect under Stack widget but when I press Register now I cant see any action with print or when I try TextButton or Inkwell they give me same result why it soendt work ?

How can I solve this problem ?

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: 0,
              child: Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.7,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/wave_purple_up.svg",
                    height: 250,
                    width: 100,
                  ))),
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 200,
              ),
              //Image
              SvgPicture.asset(
                "assets/images/welcome.svg",
                height: 100,
              ),
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 100,
              // ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    height: 320,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffF3F3F5),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        RoundedInputField(
                          isEmail: true,
                          isPassword: false,
                          hintText: "E-mail",
                          icon: Icons.mail,
                          onChange: (value) {},
                        ),
                        RoundedInputField(
                          isEmail: false,
                          isPassword: true,
                          hintText: "Password",
                          icon: Icons.lock,
                          onChange: (value) {},
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Forgot Password ?",
                          style: AppTextStyle.MINI_BOLD_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
                        ),
                        RoundedButton(
                          text: "LOGIN",
                          press: () {},
                          color: Color(0xFF3F3D56),
                        )
                        //InputText
                        //InputText
                        //Text
                        //Buton
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                      indent: 50,
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    )),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "Or Contunie with",
                          style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                      endIndent: 50,
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SquareBox(
                    imagePath: "assets/logo/google.png",
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 25,
                  ),
                  SquareBox(
                    imagePath: "assets/logo/apple-logo.png",
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Not a member ?",
                    style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 4,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("PRESSED");
                    },
                    child: Text("Register Now",
                        style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              )
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.1,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/wave-grey_down.svg",
                    height: 300,
                    width: 100,
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also this is main code:

```
import 'package:basic_flutter_project_ui/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, body: LoginScreen());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware what `print` even does? It doesn't show anything to the user. It prints to the console

Comment: I know I cant see anything on console.

Comment: Before the print I used navigator but I want to describe my problem basicly

Comment: I simplified your code (removing svg images and text styles) and it does work as it should be. https://dartpad.dev/?id=322c4aebe5491f9d3188d085ee0535e6

Comment: @duyc Try setting `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,` on the `GestureDector` and see if that works.

Comment: For me the code also works fine

Comment: Maybe you're running on debug mode and your app freezes because of an error?

Comment: behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, also not working

Comment: I cant understand why this is not working on my project?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan no it working normal mode

Comment: I also edited my topic and add my main code which is calling loginScreen

Comment: I fodun the reason but I dont know why when I remove the last Positioned element it works but why ?

Comment: Maybe it's covering the button

Answer (score 0):

Add  `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque`
to your GestureDetector Widget

```
 class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: 0,
              child: Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.7,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/wave_purple_up.svg",
                    height: 250,
                    width: 100,
                  ))),
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 200,
              ),
              //Image
              SvgPicture.asset(
                "assets/images/welcome.svg",
                height: 100,
              ),
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 100,
              // ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    height: 320,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffF3F3F5),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        RoundedInputField(
                          isEmail: true,
                          isPassword: false,
                          hintText: "E-mail",
                          icon: Icons.mail,
                          onChange: (value) {},
                        ),
                        RoundedInputField(
                          isEmail: false,
                          isPassword: true,
                          hintText: "Password",
                          icon: Icons.lock,
                          onChange: (value) {},
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Forgot Password ?",
                          style: AppTextStyle.MINI_BOLD_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
                        ),
                        RoundedButton(
                          text: "LOGIN",
                          press: () {},
                          color: Color(0xFF3F3D56),
                        )
                        //InputText
                        //InputText
                        //Text
                        //Buton
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                      indent: 50,
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    )),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "Or Contunie with",
                          style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                      endIndent: 50,
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SquareBox(
                    imagePath: "assets/logo/google.png",
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 25,
                  ),
                  SquareBox(
                    imagePath: "assets/logo/apple-logo.png",
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Not a member ?",
                    style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 4,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                    onTap: () {
                      print("PRESSED");
                    },
                    child: Text("Register Now",
                        style: AppTextStyle.MINI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              )
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.1,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/wave-grey_down.svg",
                    height: 300,
                    width: 100,
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```